# У тебя из предков кто-то есть с востока/Востока?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать здесь про эту часть света?

> У тебя из предков кто-то есть с востока/Востока? Ну, восточных кровей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно с большой:

*У тебя из предков кто-то есть с Востока? Ну, восточных кровей?*

На **[new.gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/139)** (§ 100, примечание 1) сказано так:

> Примечание 1. Названия стран света (*север, юг, восток, запад, юго-восток, северо-запад* и т.д.) пишутся со строчной буквы, например: *пароход взял курс на юг, а затем повернул на запад*.
>
> Но когда они заменяют территориальные названия, то пишутся с прописной буквы, например: *языки народов Севера и Востока*.

То же написано у **[Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=84)** (§ 172):

> Названия стран света, употребляющиеся как территориальные названия или входящие в состав таких названий, пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.: страны Запада, осваивать Север, народы Востока, Дальний Восток, Ближний Восток, Крайний Север, Война Севера и Юга (в истории США), Северо-Запад (Северо-Западный регион России), Юго-Запад(район Москвы). Как названия стран света, направлений в пространстве эти слова пишутся со строчной буквы: восток, запад, север, юг, северо-запад, юго-восток.

Comment: Что значит new gramota.ru?

Comment: @Серж Название известного портала, посвященного русскому языку, — «Грамота.ру».

Comment: Если быть точным, это не название портала (оно не изменилось), а начало адресной строки, ведущей на сайт.

Comment: Это понятно, но почему new? С порталом я знаком.

Comment: @Серж В адресной строке самой написано new.

Comment: Я понял. Дизайн Грамоты изменился. Поэтому написано new. На тот момент, когда я спросил, ещё был старый дизайн.